# Envelope Theorem for Non-Open Sets?

Tags: general-topology

I was watching this video on the Envelope Theorem : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DiRwRERgglw

[image]

In this video, the presenter makes the distinction that "X" and "Thetha" are "Open Sets". I read this link here on Open Sets (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_set) and the general idea makes sense. However, I have the following question:

- In the case of the Envelope Theorem, why do "X" and "Thetha" have to be Open Sets - would this theorem still be valid if "X" and "Thetha" were Closed Sets?

As a final remark: Based on the Red Circle and Blue Circle illustration of Open Sets and Closed Sets (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_set), it seems that there isn't a big difference (e.g. perimeter, surface area) in terms of the elements that are contained in Open Sets vs. Closed Sets.

Thank you!

Comment: It would be much better if you would tell us what $X$ and $\theta$ are, instead of expecting us to watch the video.

Comment: You have put a bounty – you want an answer – you're more likely to get one, if you engage with comments from a user who is trying to help you.

Comment: Hello! I believe X is the solution function and X is a function of thetha. Both X and Thetha are open sets. - However, I have watched the video a few times and I am still not sure..

Answer (score 2):

The reason the lecturer works with open sets in this video is that in order to take a derivative, one needs a neighborhood around every point to be contained within the domain. In other words, the domain must be open.

One easy way to extend differentiability to closed convex sets is to consider a [one-sided derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-differentiability). The idea is that at the endpoints $a,b$ of the closed convex set $[a,b]$, half of the neighborhood around these points is contained within the domain. Thus, we can take "half" of a derivative there. One then can define the derivative in the same way on $(a,b)$ and as the one-sided derivative on $a$ and $b$, and most proofs of theorems for $C^1$ functions on open sets remain nearly the same when extending to similar functions on closed convex sets.

The Envelope Theorem does seem to extend to even more sets according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_theorem). However, it seems one needs an entirely different proof such as Milgrom and Segal's result for absolutely continuous functions from their $2002$ paper "Envelope theorem for arbitrary choice sets".